# saving 3 forms with one submit Angular 10

Tags: angular, typescript, api

im trying to save 3 forms of an angular stepper at the same time knowing that products (secondFormGroup) and value(thirdFormGroup) could contain multiple rows

the Api model looks like this :

```
{
  "product": [
    {
      "description": "string",
      "id": 0,
      "name": "string",
      "priority": 0,
      "store": {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "string",
      "type": "PROPERTIES",
      "version": 0
    },
    "values": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "value": "string"
      }
     ]
    }
  ],
  "store": {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "string",
    "type": "PROPERTIES",
    "version": 0
  }
}
```

this is my code

```
@Input() firstFormGroup!: FormGroup;
@Input() secondFormGroup!: FormGroup;
@Input() thirdFormGroup!: FormGroup;
@Input() products!: IProduct[];
@Input() values!: IValue[];

constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

  this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
   name: ['', Validators.required],
   type: ['', Validators.required],
  });


  this.secondFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
   name: ['', Validators.required],
   description: ['', Validators.required],
   priority: ['', Validators.required],
  });

  this.thirdFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
   value: [null, [Validators.required]],
  });

}
```

this my service :

```
createStore(storeInfo: IStore): Observable<EntityResponseType> {
  return this.http.post<IStore>(this.CSstoreUrl, storeInfo, { observe: 'response' });
 }
```

if anyone could help please

im having a 400 error

[this is what the network tab shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63dV3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not [group](http://value:%20%5Bnull,%20%5BValidators.required%5D%5D) all your stepper forms into one nested group/array with [formArray](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#creating-dynamic-forms) with something like this (please check the documentation links for fully correct syntax) :

```
this.fullForm = this._formBuilder.group({ // will have structure of IStore
    store : this.firstFormGroup,
    product : this._formBuilder.array([ // matches the array of forms
        this._formBuilder.group({ 
            name: ['', Validators.required],
            description: ['', Validators.required],
            priority: ['', Validators.required],
            values: this._formBuilder.array([ // array in the array of forms
                this._formBuilder.control('', Validators.required)
            ])
        })
    ])
    
})
```

This way, the form would output a value object matching the expected API structure.

```
this.fullForm.value // has structure of the forms (minus the disabled ones)
this.fullForm.valueChanges.subscribe(change => console.log(change)) // shows every value change
```

To debug more, you can also add this in your template :

```
<pre>{{fullForm.value | json}}</pre>
```

Comment: thanx for the answer but my problem is how to post it and save it in my database .. i got the 400 error (Bad Request)

Comment: In that case, you need to check what is causing the 400, either through a network tab from a browser devtool (check also what was sent), or through the backend's stacktrace.

Comment: im saving the form like this :                                                                                  
 const result = Object.assign({}, this.fullForm.value);   
      
 this.storeService.createStore(result);  throught the network tab i got that all the field stays empty  i edited my post  to let you see  what the tab shows